# C# Selenium - How do you take a screenshot in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2015

I need some help when it comes to taking a screenshot in visual studio 2015 using selenium and C#. I keep getting an error message when running the code below.

```
            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
            ss.SaveAsFile(@"C:\Temp\Download\Image.png", 
            ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

The error message I get is "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalExcepton: A generic error occurred in GDI+"

If anyone is currently able to take screenshots, please let me know if you are doing anything differently.

Comment: I haven't used `ScreenshotImageFormat`. Have you looked at [this answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18660838/1183506)

Comment: I have looked at that answer, that's actually what I tried first but using `ss.SaveAsFile(@"D:\Screenshots\SeleniumTestingScreenshot.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);` results in a message telling me that `ImageFormat` is obsolete.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not seeing anything in the documentation saying it's obsolete, but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. I assume you're on `.NET 4.6.2`?

Comment: Nevermind, I realized it's the `SaveAsFile(string, ImageFormat)` that is marked obsolete in the latest webdriver, not `ImageFormat` itself. At any rate, have you made sure your application has write access to that folder? Can you create a simple file or is this just an issue with screenshots?

Comment: I'm not sure how to verify whether or not I have write access, could you point me in the right direction to check for that?

Comment: You could try executing a line like this `using (File.Create(filename)) ;` Just make sure your file is in the same location you're trying to save the screenshot to. If that works in your code, write access probably isn't the issue.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @mrfreester, I finally figured it out! You were right in your suspicion with the problem having to do with the `SaveAsFile`, not sure if it was a write access issue but there was definitely something wrong with the way I had the file path setup. Once I changed that, it started working.

Comment: Great! Feel free to post your final solution as an answer for others with the same problem :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: 'ImageFormat' is obsolete. Instead use 'ScreenshotImageFormat'.

Answer (score 9):

Finally!

I found that there was an issue with the way that I had the file path setup, I changed my initial code to the following code and now it's working.

```
        Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
        ss.SaveAsFile("C://Image.png", 
        ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

**Note**
This will save on your C: drive.

Comment: You might want to add a time stamp to your image name otherwise you will probably run into problems with "file already exists".

Answer (score 0):

using this you can save the picture to your computer and show it in the picturebox

```
drv.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
ITakesScreenshot screenshot= drv as ITakesScreenshot;
Screenshot screenshot1 = screenshot.GetScreenshot();
screenshot1.SaveAsFile(@"D:\KayıtResmi.png",ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
screenshot1.SaveAsFile(@"D:\KayıtResmi.png",ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"D:\KayıtResmi.png");
pictureBox1.Image = (Image)bitmap;
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
```